# Problems when importing a module in TypeScript 4

Tags: typescript, deno

I'm learning TypeScript, my development environment is:

- TS v4.7.4
- deno 1.24.2 (release, x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu) as compiler
- JavaScript language version used: ES2016
- Editor: Visual Studio Code
- plugins installed: JavaScript and TypeScript Nightly v4.9, TypeScript Importer v2.0.1, TypeScript Toolbox v0.5.0

I'm following an old tutorial (which uses TS 4.1.3 with node.js and ES5 for JS), and I have
a certain questions with this exercise:

- Create `types/AuthTypes.d.ts` with this content:

```
declare module 'AuthTypes' {
  export interface User {
    email: string
    roles: Array<string>
    source?: string
  }
}
```

- Create `user.ts` with this initial content:

```
///<reference path = './types/AuthTypes.d.ts'/>
import auth = require('AuthTypes')

let alice: auth.User
alice = {
  email: 'alice@snow.com',
  roles: ['super_admin'],
  source: 'facebook',
  amigo: 'chesu'
}

console.log(alice);
```

I'm getting three error messages from linter:

1. Import assignment cannot be used when targeting ECMAScript modules. Consider using 'import * as ns from "mod"', 'import {a} from "mod"', 'import d from "mod"', or another module format instead.
2. Relative import path "AuthTypes" not prefixed with / or ./ or ../
3. Type '{ email: string; roles: string[]; source: string; amigo: string; }' is not assignable to type 'User'.
   Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'amigo' does not exist in type 'User'.

The third error is expected. So I changed

```
///<reference path = './types/AuthTypes.d.ts'/>
import auth = require('AuthTypes')
```

with this line:

```
import * as auth from './types/AuthTypes.d.ts'
```

The program is running now with no errors when it should not because the nonexisting property `amigo`. How should this problem be properly solved?

Comment: Try `export declare module 'AuthTypes'`

Comment: I'm getting a new error now: `'export' modifier cannot be applied to ambient modules and module augmentations since they are always visible.`

Comment: try to `import` the User directly : try `import {User} from 'AuthTypes'`

Comment: I tried it and I'm still getting error from `export ` so I removed `export` from module, and I'm getting no errors now (expected an error from `amigo`). So there is a problem yet.

Comment: make a change in your tsconfig.json `{ compilerOptions"  { "esModuleInterop": true,}}`

Comment: that option was already set

Answer (score 0):

That problem was (almost) resolved thanks to this [video](https://youtu.be/5HvpEiDgU2s).

My new content for `types/AuthTypes.d.ts` file is like this:

```
export interface User {
  email: string
  roles: Array<string>
  source?: string
}
```

and for `user.ts` is:

```
import * as auth from './types/AuthTypes.d.ts'

let alice: auth.User
alice = {
  email: 'alice@snow.com',
  roles: ['super_admin'],
  source: 'facebook',
  amigo: 'chesu'
}

console.log(alice);
```

With this change every exported classes and their properties are properly recognized, and I'm getting the expected error message on property `amigo` (on IDE) only.